# Ruby Stomp Gem #publish seems to truncate messages to 256 characters?

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but

```
client = Stomp::Client.new('user', 'pass', activemq_host, port)
client.publish('com.real.queue', some_really_large_object.to_json, { :persistent => true })
```

results in messages getting cut off after 256 characters...  I have not been able to find any good documentation explaining where this limit comes from (doesn't seem to be a configuration option in the stomp ruby gem), and apparently other people who use different clients can post to the queue and not see messages get truncated...

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is it really 256 chars when you consume the message with another client or simply in hawt.io or some JMX console? Because reading messages with Hawt.io gives 256 chars for byte message

Comment: hard to know really--- but the message literally showed the length was 256, and when I set the option to suppress_content_length, messages showed the real correct length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using the following for headers solved the problem:

```
{ 'persistent' => true,                                                                                                                              
  'suppress_content_length' => true,                                                                                                                                
   'content-type' => 'application/json' }
```